# Yoast SEO settings unavailable in an archive page from wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, archives, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

My Wordpress site has "[Seriously Simple Podcasting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seriously-simple-podcasting/)" plugin installed to serve the podcast feature.

This plugin comes with a [podcast archive page](https://salesforceway.com/podcast/)(click to open) on my site. The page shows correctly for users, but lacking 2 important SEO functions:

1. Yoast plugin is unavailable/invisible, i.e. I cannot set `search keyword`, `meta description` etc for this archive page.
2. I cannot change the H1 title from `Podcast Archive` to whatever I'd like to have

What can I do to achieve the 2 SEO goals above, **whether configuring, installing extra plugins or extending php code**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yoast SEO can have limitations for archive pages. Try a different SEO plugin such as Rank Math perhaps.
   Your other option would be to open the archive.php file of your theme and add your custom code in there if required.
   You may also contact the developers of that podcasting plugin to see if they have a solution.
2. That title is inserted through your theme. You can open the file archive.php and look for the insertion of headings. Change those headings in there but be aware that it will change on all archive pages/categories. For that reason it is advisable to modify it through your podcasting plugin.

Comment: Thanks for recommending Rank Math. It has a podcast archive settings which solves my problem straight away.